# NameError: name '' is not defined, trying to make a to-do list CLI app

Tags: python, pickle, nameerror

So as the title suggests I'm trying to do a to-do list CLI app, and I've been getting that error. (`NameError: name 'loaded_uinput' is not defined`)

When I set loaded_uinput to a global variable it gives me that error, but if I don't it gives me this one: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'loaded_uinput' referenced before assignment`

I've been trying to research all day looking for what I have been doing wrong, but aside from it being badly written code (for now, I'm planning on refactoring it really soon), I can't find it :/

```
userlist = []
filename = "userdata.p"

def maininput():
    while True:
        #Selecting if user wants to read or write the list, and or exit
        init_conf = input("Would you like to read or write your list? (read | write | exit)")
        #Printing the list
        if init_conf == "read":
            pickle_in = open(filename, "rb")
            loaded_uinput = pickle.load(pickle_in, encoding='bytes')
            pickle_in.close()
            print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")
        #Customizing the list
        elif init_conf == "write":
            uinput = input("What would you like to add to your list?")
            userlist.append("-" + uinput)
            pickle_out = open(filename, "ab")
            pickle.dump(userlist, pickle_out)
            pickle_out.close()
            print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")
        elif init_conf == "exit":
            break

maininput()
```

I just want this to run without errors haha, don't even understand how it's saying that it isn't defined when it really seems like it is :/ 
I want to write something and have that be stored in `userdata.p`

Thank you!

Comment: If you try to `write` before you `read`, `loaded_uinput` won't be set yet.

Comment: @Barmar but it's reading before writing?

Comment: Are you calling `maininput()` multiple times? Each time you call it, it starts fresh, so you have to read first.

Comment: @Balmar I am not ^^

Comment: Then the error shouldn't happen if you always do `read` first.

Comment: If you define it as a global variable, you should put `global loaded_uinput` in the function and do `loaded_uinput = []` before calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the variable before the loop. It is created only in the 'if' block scope, and not when you get to the 'elif' block, where you are trying to access it. You can set it to an empty list if you want.

```
userlist = []
filename = "userdata.p"

def maininput():
    loaded_uinput = []
    while True:
        #Selecting if user wants to read or write the list, and or exit
        init_conf = input("Would you like to read or write your list? (read | write | exit)")
        #Printing the list
        if init_conf == "read":
            pickle_in = open(filename, "rb")
            loaded_uinput = pickle.load(pickle_in, encoding='bytes')
            pickle_in.close()
            print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")
        #Customizing the list
        elif init_conf == "write":
            uinput = input("What would you like to add to your list?")
            userlist.append("-" + uinput)
            pickle_out = open(filename, "ab")
            pickle.dump(userlist, pickle_out)
            pickle_out.close()
            print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")
        elif init_conf == "exit":
            break

maininput()
```

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to be a list, since it's printed with `*loaded_uinput`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not define `loaded_uinput` as a global variable outside of the function. The `UnboundLocalError` appears if you try to use `loaded_uinput` before it is defined, which can happen if `init_conf == "write"` is `True` in the very first iteration of the while loop. That is, if you type `"write"` the very first time, `loaded_uinput` will not be defined when it tries to use it for the printout.

Comment: Is the first sentence backwards?

Comment: I don't see why you would think that.

Comment: It's not defining it as a global variable, so why are you saying not to? If they did, they wouldn't get the error.

Comment: Defining `loaded_uinput` as a global variable was mentioned in the question. "When I set loaded_uinput to a global variable it gives me that error"

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because you are trying to access the `loaded_uinput` variable before assigning any value to it.

When the loop runs for the first time and 'write' command is entered, the loop gets the gets the data input to `uinput` and save it to file but tries to print `print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")` which is not yet assigned. It should be changed to:

```py
print(*uinput)
```

`open(filename, "ab")` was changed to replace the file's contents instead of appending to it.

```py
open(filename, "wb")
```

Check this working code:

```
import pickle
userlist = []
filename = "userdata.p"

def maininput():
    while True:
        #Selecting if user wants to read or write the list, and or exit
        init_conf = input("Would you like to read or write your list? (read | write | exit)")
        #Printing the list
        if init_conf == "read":
            pickle_in = open(filename, "rb")
            loaded_uinput = pickle.load(pickle_in)
            pickle_in.close()
            print(*loaded_uinput, sep="\n")
        #Customizing the list
        elif init_conf == "write":
            uinput = input("What would you like to add to your list?")
            userlist.append("-" + uinput)
            pickle_out = open(filename, "wb")
            pickle.dump(userlist, pickle_out)
            pickle_out.close()
            print(*uinput)
        elif init_conf == "exit":
            break

maininput()
```

Working example here: https://repl.it/repls/VapidDescriptiveMiddleware